# Javascript submit to mysql replay will replace div

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, mysql

Am trying to send data to a MYSQL php script i have (that works) and that script "echo" back what ever i want. 
The Script php file is fully working and i can select what to echo back on succes. But now i want to try switch from HTML to Javascript to replace a div without pageload.

Maybe the script i uses right now is the wrong kind o script.

Page looks like this

```
<div id="Wrapper"> 
 <div id="std_img"
  //Here i have a img and a form with a submit button that sends the input data to my phpfile. 
 </div>


</div>
```

Now what i want to do is to replace the  depends on the echo.
Lets say i echo back div id´s. So it would hide  and display

Here is how my script look so far.

```
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
<!-- 
//Browser Support Code
function ajaxFunction(){
    var ajaxRequest;  // The variable that makes Ajax possible!

    try{
        // Opera 8.0+, Firefox, Safari
        ajaxRequest = new XMLHttpRequest();
    } catch (e){
        // Internet Explorer Browsers
        try{
            ajaxRequest = new ActiveXObject("Msxml2.XMLHTTP");
        } catch (e) {
            try{
                ajaxRequest = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
            } catch (e){
                // Something went wrong
                alert("Your browser broke!");
                return false;
            }
        }
    }
    // Create a function that will receive data sent from the server
    ajaxRequest.onreadystatechange = function(){
        if(ajaxRequest.readyState == 4){
            var ajaxDisplay = document.getElementById('ajaxDiv');
            ajaxDisplay.innerHTML = ajaxRequest.responseText;
        }
    }

    var sex = document.getElementById('vipcode').value;
    var sex = document.getElementById('userid').value;
    var sex = document.getElementById('username').value;
    var queryString = "?vipcode=" + vipcode + "&username=" + username + "&userid=" + userid;
    ajaxRequest.open("GET","<?php echo plugins_url('valdate.php', __FILE__) ?> " + queryString, true);
    ajaxRequest.send(null); 
}

//-->
</script>





<form name="activatevip">
 <input name="vipcode" id="vipcode" type="text" placeholder="Write code here">
 <input class='button-primary' type='button' onclick='ajaxFunction()' value='Activate' />
<p>
    <input type="hidden" id="userid" value="<?php echo $current_user->ID ?>">
  <input type="hidden" id="username" value="<?php echo $current_user->user_login ?>">
  </p>

</form>

<div id='ajaxDiv'>ECHO is shown here</div> // is there a way of insted display an output to replace an div?
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not correct.

```
var sex = document.getElementById('vipcode').value;
var sex = document.getElementById('userid').value;
var sex = document.getElementById('username').value;
```

You cannot have the same variable names. Change them as `vipcode`, `userid`, `username`

```
var vipcode = document.getElementById('vipcode').value;
var userid = document.getElementById('userid').value;
var username = document.getElementById('username').value;
var queryString = "?vipcode=" + vipcode + "&username=" + username + "&userid=" + userid;
```

PS: I liked your variable names, `sex`. Smooth. But sorry to see it go.

Comment: Thanks was a typo, and i think i answerd to my own question. Here i try to replace a div. When my script does that without any another things added. Time to wakeup for me now! Thank you